# Dictionary using an object as a key C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
private readonly Dictionary<ExcelCellIdentifier, int> allInfoByIdentifier = new Dictionary<ExcelCellIdentifier, int>();

public class ExcelCellIdentifier
{
    public ExcelCellIdentifier(string ticker, string identifier)
    {
        Ticker = ticker;
        Identifier = identifier;
    }
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

Then at some point I would like to search for the int by creating an ExcelCellIdentifier object with the same ticker and identifier, like:

```
ExcelCellIdentifier ex = new ExcelCellIdentifier("Ticker1", "Identifier1");
int a = allInfoByIdentifier[ex];
//a is a value stored before hand
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You have either typed this code or copied it from something. Either way this is code that now exists. In the time it took you to make this post you could have simply shoved it into Visual Studio and hit F5. If you have tried it already and are having problems, please let us know what the problems were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because no one else has given you a proper version using IEquateable here you go

```
public class ExcelCellIdentifier : IEquatable<ExcelCellIdentifier>
{
   public ExcelCellIdentifier(string ticker, string identifier)
   {
        Ticker = ticker;
        Identifier = identifier;
   }

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
      var identifier = obj as ExcelCellIdentifier;
      if(identifier == null)
          return false;
      else
          return Equals(identifier);
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
      //All this below is a common performance thing I add, if you have the two strings "Foo" and "Bar" it will give you a different hash code than the string "Bar" and "Foo", it gives you a better distribution of the hash.
      unchecked
      {
          int hash = 17;
          hash = hash * 23 + Ticker.GetHashCode();
          hash =  hash * 23 + Identifier.GetHashCode();
          return hash;
      }
   }

   public string Ticker { get; set; } //This should likely be changed to {get; private set;}
   public string Identifier { get; set; } //This should likely be changed to {get; private set;}

   public bool Equals(ExcelCellIdentifier other)
   {
      return Ticker.Equals(other.Ticker) && Identifier.Equals(other.Identifier);
   }
}
```

---

Change these two methods to the following to remove case sensitivity to the strings

```
   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
      //All this below is a common performance thing I add, if you have the two strings "Foo" and "Bar" it will give you a different hash code than the string "Bar" and "Foo", it gives you a better distribution of the hash.
      unchecked
      {
          int hash = 17;
          hash = hash * 23 + StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(Ticker);
          hash =  hash * 23 + StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(Identifier);
          return hash;
      }
   }

   public string Ticker { get; set; } //This should likely be changed to {get; private set;}
   public string Identifier { get; set; } //This should likely be changed to {get; private set;}

   public bool Equals(ExcelCellIdentifier other)
   {
      return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(Ticker, other.Ticker) && StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(Identifier, other.Identifier);
   }
```

Comment: Refresh, I made a few miskates at first, and I override `int GetHashCode()` the other code is doing `int GetHashCode(ExcelCellIdentifier obj)` which is wrong for IEquateable.

Comment: And what is the unchecked block?

Comment: 99% of the time it is not needed, as it is already the default behavior, but if you set your compiler to do [checked arithmetic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) you will get a `OverflowExecption` if the value of `hash` becomes more than `int.MAX_VALUE`. If you are unchecked it just wraps around to `int.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: It still doesn't find it

Comment: Oops, i made a mistake in Equals, it should have been `Ticker.Equals(other.Ticker) && Identifier.Equals(other.Identifier);` I also added a case insensitive version too.

Comment: Ok, got it to work. Thanks a lot :D I still don't get your method of calculating the hash. I don't even understand the comment.

Comment: Lets say the string `Foo` returns a hash of `1` and the string `Bar` returns a hash of `2`, If I had `Foo` for `Ticker` and `Bar` for `Identifier` just adding them gives me `3` by using my method it gives me `9018`. Now if I reverse it so `Ticker` is `Bar` and `Identifer` is `Foo` adding still gives me `3` but using my method it gives me `9040`, so I get two different has codes for swapping the values of `Ticket` and `Identifier`, this helps give better performance when dealing with lots of items in your dictionary.

Comment: Are 17 and 23 and addition arbitrary, or is it an actual formula for calculating hash?

Comment: Arbitrary, they are both non small prime numbers to help make collisions less frequent. The pattern is the initial number is `hash = X` then every property you add to the hash is `hash = Y * hash + newValue`. `X` must be non 0 and `Y` must be > 1.

Comment: That makes much more sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` requires an equality implementation to determine whether keys are equal. You can specify an implementation of the [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) generic interface by using a constructor that accepts a *comparer* parameter; if you do not specify an implementation, the default generic equality comparer [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) is used. If type *TKey* implements the [`System.IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) generic interface, the default equality comparer uses that implementation.

It's up to you to decide how you want equality to work in this case - either provide a comparer when you construct the dictionary or implement `IEquatable<T>`. The middle option doesn't work for you, since the default comparer for reference types uses reference equality.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do this as long as you either implement `IEquatable<ExcelCellIdentifier>` in your `ExcelCellIdentifier` class, or instantiate the dictionary with an instance of `IEqualityComparer<ExcelCellIdentifier>`.

One important thing to remember is that although I don't think `IEquatable<T>` forces you to override `GetHashCode()` (even though as commented below it's mandated in the documentation), you need to make sure you override it appropriately, otherwise even if your objects return true for `Equals()`, one won't work as a key to find the other in the dictionary.

This is a cause of lots of fun debugging where you're *sure* your equality comparer is working fine, but somehow your dictionary isn't retrieving anything!

For my money, I prefer to implement a custom equality comparer, which keeps the business of managing your dictionary separate from the implementation of your class:

```
    private readonly Dictionary<ExcelCellIdentifier, int> allInfoByIdentifier =
        new Dictionary<ExcelCellIdentifier, int>(new ExcelCellIdentifierComparer());

    public class ExcelCellIdentifier
    {
        private ExcelCellIdentifier(string ticker, string identifier)
        {
            Ticker = ticker;
            Identifier = identifier;
        }

        public string Ticker { get; set; }

        public string Identifier { get; set; }

    }

    private class ExcelCellIdentifierComparer : IEqualityComparer<ExcelCellIdentifier>
    {
        public bool Equals(ExcelCellIdentifier x, ExcelCellIdentifier y)
        {
            return x.Identifier == y.Identifier && x.Ticker == y.Ticker;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(ExcelCellIdentifier obj)
        {
            return obj.Identifier.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Ticker.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `IEquateable<T>` does "require" you to overide `GetHashCode()` and overide `Equals(obj)`. If you read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) and read the "Notes to Implementers" section it says you must do it. Never use a API without reading the documentation, just because the interface does not auto generate something does not mean you don't have to do extra work for it to work properly.

Comment: I meant require as in "won't compile if you don't"

Comment: There is a lot more to programming than just getting something to compile, that is why I said you should always read the documentation.

Comment: Wise words, @ScottChamberlain. In the context of my answer, would you not agree that it was worth pointing out this potential gotcha though? I didn't feel I should just assume the questioner had read all the relevant documentation. The docs also tell you to override equality and inequality operators, which although nice to have, are not _as_ necessary as properly implementing GetHashCode()

Comment: Oh, no, I am in full agreement with you, I just did not like the original word choice (I think the change from "requires" to "forces" was a very good idea)

Answer (score 0):

as Damien_The_Unbeliever said, what you need is:

```
public class myClass
{
  private readonly Dictionary<ExcelCellIdentifier, int> allInfoByIdentifier =
  new Dictionary<ExcelCellIdentifier, int>(new ExcelCellIdentifier());

  public void testIt()
  {
     allInfoByIdentifier.Add(new ExcelCellIdentifier("Ticker1", "Identifier1"), 4);
     ExcelCellIdentifier ex = new ExcelCellIdentifier("Ticker1", "Identifier1");
     int a = allInfoByIdentifier[ex];
  }
}

   public class ExcelCellIdentifier : IEqualityComparer<ExcelCellIdentifier>
{
  public ExcelCellIdentifier()
  {

  }
    public ExcelCellIdentifier(string ticker, string identifier)
    {
        Ticker = ticker;
        Identifier = identifier;
    }

    public string Ticker { get; set; }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(ExcelCellIdentifier x, ExcelCellIdentifier y)
    {
       return x.Identifier == y.Identifier && 
          x.Ticker == y.Ticker;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ExcelCellIdentifier obj)
    {
       return obj.Identifier.GetHashCode() ^ 
          obj.Ticker.GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

Comment: One thing though, the properties `GetHashCode` and `Equals` rely on must be immutable while the object is acting as a key in the collection. Changing a value while it still is held by the collection will cause errors in your program. A easy way to protect yourself from accidentally changing the values is change the properties to `{ get; private set; }`

Comment: Also you used the wrong interface, you should have used `IEquateable<T>`, `IEqualityComparer<T>` is for creating a separate comparer class. See the last line from Damien's quote.

Comment: This is a bit of an odd way to do it, you're implementing the equality comparer (the object you pass to the dictionary to tell it how to handle comparison) in the same class as the dictionary key. Either implement IEquatable or separate into two classes

Comment: I get a warning that says it override Object.Equals(object o) but does not override Object.GetHashCode()

Comment: @Alexey you can add override to hashcode or ignore the warning

Comment: @LiranElisha your code is still wrong, `public int GetHashCode(ExcelCellIdentifier obj)` is not a member of IEquateable,you should be overriding the base class `GetHashCode` correctly instead, you can not "ignore the warning" it is warning you because your code is wrong.

Comment: If I override it, it says it is not a suitable method to override

Comment: dear @Alexey, i've edited my answer, run it on 3.5, got no error or warning and got the value.